# Get widget locations in WordPress plugin

Tags: widgets

I'm writing a plugin and i am searching for a function (preferably a WP function) that returns all sidebar id's that have my widget in them.

For example : i placed my widget in sidebar1 and sidebar2, the function would return the ID of sidebar1 and sidebar2.

I realise that i can use a SQL query, but that's not an aproach that i'm fond off.
I can't find anything on this matter so i'm hoping someone here has an answer :).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such function.

There is - or better was, since it is deprecated since 2.8.1; it is of course [sic!] still in use all over the place in core - the function [`wp_get_sidebars_widgets()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sidebars_widgets) - [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/widgets.php#L1209) - which gives back an array of all sidebars with their widgets. So thinking long term you probably should use this one, although it's used heavily in core.

Generally, take a look at the source link above. But to mention it here, there are other possibilities, like the globals `$_wp_sidebars_widgets` or `$sidebars_widgets`. And you can get the same information like this:

```
get_option('sidebars_widgets', array())
```

From there, so from the information of the globals `$_wp_sidebars_widgets` or `$sidebars_widgets` or the `sidebar_widhets` option, you have to do some kind of search on the array to receive back the according sidebar ids.

Comment: Thank you for the information, it says in the codex that it is not inteded to use wp_get_sidebars_widgets() in a plugin. However, i found a way to build my plugin without the need of such a function, i found a better way :).

Comment: As I said, you shouldn't use that function. If there is a better was, then share it :) @wpj07